# SQL - Joining a table with repeated keys

Tags: sql, join

I'm working on learning SQL JOINs but I'm having trouble understanding what type of join to use in a given scenario. I would appreciate any links/recommendations to material that explains JOIN usage better!

Below is a specific scenario I don't understand:

### Basic table structure

```
'Orders' table
--
OrderNumber, CustomerID, ...

'Order_Details' table
--
OrderNumber, ProductID, ...
```

### Example:

```
Orders
--
1000, 1
1001, 2
1002, 1
1003, 1
...

Order_Details
--
1000, Product1
1000, Product2
1000, Product3
1001, Product2
1001, Product3
...
```

Desired result: I want a list of all products sold to a specific customer. I know that the OrderNumber is the 'link/key' between the two tables, but I'm just not sure what type of query to use.

### Example result:

```
CustomerID | ProductID
1            Product1
1            Product2
1            Product3
1            Product2
...
```

What type of query can I use to achieve this result?

Comment: From what you are describing a standard `JOIN` is what you want. Here is some recommended reading: http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: specifically in this case, it's an `INNER JOIN`.  There's several different forms of joins, but the most commonly used one (and the one that is used by default by most (all?) recent database systems is the `INNER JOIN`.  There's a few other types of joins, but this is probably the most common that you'll run into.

Answer (score 1):

If you want this: "a list of all products sold to a specific customer"

then what you want is this (replace 1 with the customer id you want to search for)

```
SELECT o.CustomerID, od.ProductID
FROM orders o
INNER JOIN order_details od ON o.OrderNumber = od.OrderNumber
WHERE o.CustomerID=1
```

Answer (score 0):

This calls for a simple, straight forward, join:

```
SELECT CustomerID, ProductID
FROM   orders o
JOIN   order_details od ON o.OrderNumber = od.OrderNumber
```